# Can you define a variable in ranges in java

Tags: java, variables, switch-statement, backend

When using variables can you define or specify that variable as all the numbers within a range like 1-10? I am using Switch statements and want to assign one of the case variables all the variables between 100-1000 without writing 900 case lines.

Comment: For ranges, you could write an `if` statement and use comparison operators `<`, `<=`, `>`, or `>=` as appropriate. Some languages support comparison in enhanced switch statements, too, but the last I knew, Java doesn't support this.

Comment: I'm assuming that by "case variables" you mean something like `case 42:` in your switch statement. Note that this isn't a variable and you aren't assigning anything. In fact, I don't know a good term we have to refer to this part of the syntax...

Comment: Do you mean in the definition of the variable or how to test if a variable is in a range?

Comment: It sounds like you want to have a single variable as multiple values at the same time which is confusing and not possible.  Please clarify with an example (perhaps in pseudo code) and provide a use case.

Comment: This sounds quite a lot like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).  I have trouble believing that your program has 900 distinct behaviors.  It is far more likely that your program has distinct behaviors for certain *ranges* of values, in which case a `switch` statement is the wrong Java element for your task.

Comment: I agree with @VGR. I think that the best solution for your overall problem is currently unknown, and you may wish to tell us more details of what it is that you are trying to do, what states and behaviors you're trying to elicit, rather than *how* you're trying to do this, because we may find out that an entirely different approach makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Perhaps you could have avoided the down-votes if you had written your Question more carefully, with a full explanation and some example code. And, actually, you still can — hit the "Edit" link to revise.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a `switch` statement for ranges, generally you need to map the ranges to specific values. They could be discrete integers, but in Java it makes sense to use `enum`s, because the `enum` definition can have a method that does the mapping.

`enum`s can be public, but they can also be private, within a class, if you don't need to use them anywhere else.

For example:

```
public class Something {
    private static enum RangeType {
        LOW(0, 10),
        MID(10, 20),
        HIGH(20, 30);

        private final int lowRange;
        private final int highRange;

        RangeType(int lowRange, int highRange) {
            this.lowRange = lowRange;
            this.highRange = highRange;
        }

        public RangeType getRange(int val) {
            for (RangeType rt : RangeType.values()) {
                if (rt.lowRange <= val && val < rt.highRange) {
                    return rt;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public int doSomething(int s) {
        int newS;

        RangeType sRange = RangeType.getRange(s);
        switch (sRange) {
        case LOW:
            newS = 15;
            break;
        case MID:
            newS = 3;
            break;
        case HIGH:
            newS = 9;
            break;
        default:
            newS = 0;
        }
        return newS;
    }

}
```

Using an enum might be overkill, but it does illustrate how the mapping can be done.